# Get WebBrowserControl's AxIWebBrowser2 Handle for use in InternetSetOption, COM issues with System.__ComObject

Tags: c#, reflection, com, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to set a proxy for only the current instance of a WebBrowserControl. The documentation is terrible but I believe that if I call `wininet.dll`'s `InternetSetOption` passing the IntPtr handle to the internal browser used by the WebBrowserControl as the first parameter then the method will only affect the current instance (and I can set a proxy using this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385114(v=VS.85).aspx).  However, the WebBrowserControl does not provide any means to access this handle.  I've spent hours googling and searching SO and it seems like this would be very helpful to a number of people but nobody has figured it out yet!

The WebBrowserControl has a property called AxIWebBrowser2 which is the COM object I need the handle for.  The interface MS uses for this is called `UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2` and has a property called `HWND` which I think is what I need.  However, `UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2` is marked `internal`.  Using reflection on the WebBrowserControl, I can get the private `AxIWebBrowser2` property value but the type on it comes up as `System.__ComObject`.  I can't cast this `System.__ComObject` as an `IWebBrowser2` because that's internal to the `Windows.Forms` assembly.

Is there any way to access the `HWND` property of this `AxIWebBrowser2` object using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hwnd won't give you what you are looking for. It's the window handle of the browser control. What are are looking for is the WinInet HINTERNET handle. There is no way to programmatically access that as far as I know. Have you tried setting the option on a process-wide basis and passing IntPtr.Zero in as the HINTERNET handle?

Comment: Yes and that works.  But as you said, it's on a process-wide basis.  I need to be able to spawn multiple threads to use multiple proxies.  An alternative would be to spawn multiple processes which each use different proxies but I tried doing something similar and it didn't seem to work right -- it seemed that the proxy was set on a global basis!

Answer (score 0):

Try configure IE to use an [proxy automatic configuration script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) that allocates proxies from a proxy pool (or just change the proxy in the http response for each web request), and [disable the automatic proxy caching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271361).